# Finding row before each coordinate change in csv via python

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have a csv with 3 columns, one of which is an id. 
For a single id, the values in one of the columns will repeat themselves through time, then suddenly change and repeat themselves again. How can I find the row for the value before each change in python and export the output? 


The catch for why I can't search the id for max timestamp, is there would need to be a row or timestamp after the change with the same id. 
In other words, the output would have to only include rows preceding a change in the coordinates column.

If an id does not have variation in coordinates across time, then those rows would not be needed for the output.

For example, finding the ones in bold.

ID | Coordinates | Timestamp

101 |  90, -1  | 2016-01-01 9:00 
101 |  90, -1  | 2016-01-01 9:01 
**101 |  90, -1  | 2016-01-01 9:02** 

101 |  90, -2  | 2016-01-01 9:03 
101 |  90, -2  | 2016-01-01 9:04 
102 |  90, -3  | 2016-01-01 9:00 
102 |  90, -3  | 2016-01-01 9:01 
**102 |  90, -3  | 2016-01-01 9:02** 

102 |  90, -4  | 2016-01-01 9:03 
102 |  90, -4  | 2016-01-01 9:04 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:00 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:01 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:02 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:03 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:04 
103 | 90, 90 | 2016-01-01 9:05 
and so on..

Comment: Will it be the same value in the coordinate column changing each time? In this example just the negative values are changing, but could it be either element?

Comment: Any change in the coordinate column. Could be either or both.

Comment: Is your csv using pipe characters as the delimiter, or commas (did you add the pipe characters for this question)?

Comment: just a regular csv - commas.

Comment: @nic7 and you don't want the last unique value (e.g. the 5th and last row of that dataframe)?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "...find the row for the value before each change in python and export the output"?

Comment: find the last row before any change in the coordinate column. Get those rows and export them to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is sorted according to time and you load in your csv using `read_csv` using pandas, you could do something simple like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102,], \
     'Coordinates': [(90, -1), (90, -1), (90, -1), (90, -2), (90, -2), (90, -3), (90, -3), (90, -3), (90, -4), (90, -4)], \
     'Timestamp': ['2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04', \
                   '2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04']})
clean_df = df.sort_values('Timestamp').drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Coordinates'], keep='last')
print(clean_df)

    ID Coordinates        Timestamp
7  102    (90, -3)  2016-01-01 9:02
2  101    (90, -1)  2016-01-01 9:02
9  102    (90, -4)  2016-01-01 9:04
4  101    (90, -2)  2016-01-01 9:04
```

if you don't mind having the last unique value.

Alternatively,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102,], \
     'Coordinates': [(90, -1), (90, -1), (90, -1), (90, -2), (90, -2), (90, -3), (90, -3), (90, -3), (90, -4), (90, -4)], \
     'Timestamp': ['2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04', \
                   '2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04']}).sort_values(by=['ID', 'Coordinates', 'Timestamp'], ascending=False)

new_df = df.loc[df['Coordinates'].shift() != df['Coordinates']]
print(new_df)

7  102    (90, -3)  2016-01-01 9:02
9  102    (90, -4)  2016-01-01 9:04
2  101    (90, -1)  2016-01-01 9:02
4  101    (90, -2)  2016-01-01 9:04
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would account for all last coordinates, correct? So if the list goes on and another ID has no coordinate movement across time, it would still be kept with this clean_df?

Comment: @nic7 Correct this would keep any unique value for `'Coordinate'` based on the latest time. An `'ID'` could have multiple unique `'Coordinate'` and `'Timestamp'` values/rows.

Comment: Thanks, almost what I'm looking for, but want to not include those that are not preceding a change in coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[101,101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102,102],
                   "Coordinates":["90,-1","90,-1","90,-1","90,-2","90,-2","90,-3","90,-3","90,-3","90,-4","90,-4"],
                   'Timestamp': ['2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04', \
                   '2016-01-01 9:00', '2016-01-01 9:01', '2016-01-01 9:02', '2016-01-01 9:03', '2016-01-01 9:04']
                   })

def f(x):
     for i in range(len(x)-1):
         if x[i] != x[i+1]:
             return i

g = df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[f(list(x.Coordinates))])
```

output

```
    ID    Coordinates Timestamp

  101       90,-1  2016-01-01 9:02
  102       90,-3  2016-01-01 9:02
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this take care of excluding any IDs without any change through time?

Comment: yes,this will only track changes in the coordinates.it doesn't care about time